# Capturing the Error in Impala using a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, impala

I am trying to execute a few impala queries using a shell script. If an impala query fails, I would like to capture the error message and write it to a text file.

Is there a way to capture the error message? Not just the exit status which can be accessed using '$?', but the actual error message given by impala.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

#### Demo

```
$ cat>myfile.sql
select 1 as col1;
select abc;
select 2 as col2;
```

---

```
$ impala-shell -f myfile.sql 1>myfile.txt 2>myfile.err
$ result=$?
```

---

```
$ echo $result 
1
```

---

```
$ cat myfile.txt
+------+
| col1 |
+------+
| 1    |
+------+
```

---

```
$ cat myfile.err
Starting Impala Shell without Kerberos authentication
Connected to quickstart.cloudera:21000
Server version: impalad version 2.5.0-cdh5.7.0 RELEASE (build ad3f5adabedf56fe6bd9eea39147c067cc552703)
Query: select 1 as col1
Fetched 1 row(s) in 0.05s
Query: select abc
ERROR: AnalysisException: Could not resolve column/field reference: 'abc'

Could not execute command: select abc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually tried it but it didn't work for me. The file always stays empty even after the query has failed. This is my query:
**_result=$(impala-shell --quiet --delimited --ssl -i ${impala_host} -ku ${user_id}${impala_realm} -q "set request_pool = ${request_pool}; use $current_directory$ENV; invalidate metadata $tbl_name; show tables like '$tbl_name';") 2>> /tmp/psk1/logsdb.txt_**

Comment: See edited answer. result=$(...) 2>> ... won't work since the redirection is not of the scope of the impala-shell.